# C++ string to bool

Tags: c++, string, boolean

I think my string to bool function doesn't work properly. It can't handle with condition -

> ! ! ! ! true &&
>   true

. It should print 1 instead of 0.

```
bool to_bool(string str) {
    transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
    istringstream is(str);
    bool b;
    is >> boolalpha >> b;
    return b;
}


int main()
{
    if(to_bool("! ! ! ! true && true"))
        cout <<1;
    else
        cout <<0;
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Standard C++ has no parsers

Comment: What does your documentation for `>>` say? Does it say that it supports arbitrary boolean expressions? Mine doesn't.

Comment: @linkas I'm unclear what you want here, are you expecting `to_bool` to take in a `string` and evaluate it as a logical expression?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, but this function handles with simple requests (like "true || false" etc.)

Comment: `>>` is not a boolean expression parser. It is simply being used to convert `"true"` or `"false"` and nothing else.

Answer (score 4):

I am surprised that no one mentioned this one:

```
bool b;
istringstream("1") >> b;
```

or

```
bool b;
istringstream("true") >> std::boolalpha >> b;
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why you expect `std::istream` to parse and evaluate boolean expressions, but according to documentation it should not that (from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get):

> If the type of v is `bool` and `boolalpha!=0`, the following replaces
>   stages 2 and 3: Successive characters obtained from the input iterator
>   in are matched against the character sequences obtained from
>   `std::use_facet<std::numpunct<charT>>(str.getloc()).falsename()` and
>   `std::use_facet<std::numpunct<charT> >(str.getloc()).truename()` only as
>   necessary as to identify the unique match. The input iterator in is
>   compared to end only when necessary to obtain a character. If the
>   target sequence is uniquely matched, v is set to the corresponding
>   bool value. Otherwise false is stored in v and `std::ios_base::failbit`
>   is assigned to err. If unique match could not be found before the
>   input ended `(in==end)`, `err|=std::ios_base::eofbit` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> It should print 1 instead of 0.

You are not checking whether `is >> boolalpha >> b;` successfully read anything into `b`.

Here's something to try:

```
is >> boolalpha >> b;
if ( ! is.good() )
{
    // Do something to deal with the error.
}
```

Comment: It is not necessary to initialize `b`

Comment: @Slava, It's not necessary but always good to initialize local variables.

Comment: maybe it is good practice, but I would not consider that as a problem in this case.

Comment: @Slava, it's not a problem per se. The OP got the wrong impression that `b` was set to `false` by `is >> boolalpha >> b;`. If `b` is initialized to `true`, hopefully they would notice that nothing was read into `b`.

Comment: Why that impression is wrong? According to documentation (see my answer) `std::istream::operator>>` does set `b` to `false` in this case.

Comment: @Slava, my misunderstanding. Thanks for clarifying. I'll update my answer.